# Find if a port is available to use in linux using c++

Tags: c++, linux, port, netstat

I am working on a C++ Project. To fulfill one of the requirement, I need to check if a port is available for using in my application anytime. To fulfill this , I have come to this following solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


std::string _executeShellCommand(std::string command) {
    char buffer[256];
    std::string result = "";
    const char * cmd = command.c_str();
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");

    try {
        while (!feof(pipe)) 
            if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
                result += buffer;
    } catch (...) {
        pclose(pipe);
        throw;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}

bool _isAvailablePort(unsigned short usPort){
    char shellCommand[256], pcPort[6];
    sprintf(shellCommand, "netstat -lntu | awk '{print $4}' | grep ':' | cut -d \":\" -f 2 | sort | uniq | grep %hu", usPort);
    sprintf(pcPort, "%hu", usPort);

    std::string output =  _executeShellCommand(std::string(shellCommand));

    if(output.find(std::string(pcPort)) != std::string::npos)
            return false;
    else
            return true;

}   


int main () {
    bool res = _isAvailablePort(5678);
    return 0;
}
```

Here Basically the `_executeShellCommand` function can excute any shell command anytime and can return the `stdout` output as return string.

And I am executing the following shell command in that function.

```
netstat -lntu | awk '{print $4}' | grep ':' | cut -d \":\" -f 2 | sort | uniq | grep portToCheck
```

So, if the port is already in use, the `_executeShellCommand` will return the PortValue itself, else it will return Blank. So, checking the returned string, I can decide.

So far so good.

Now, I want to be make my Project completely Crash-proof. So, before firing the `netstat` command, I want to make sure if it really exists or not. I want help in this case. I know, It's kind of stupid to doubt the availability of `netstat` command in a linux machine. I am just thinking of some user who removed `netstat` binary from his machine for some reason.

N.B. : I don't want make a `bind()` call to chack if the port is available or not. Also, it will be best if I can check if `netstat` command is available without calling `_executeShellCommand` for another time (i.e. without executing another Shell Command).

Comment: There are more commands you can use like `whereis netstat` or so, and check the output.

Comment: Note that you'll have to handle the case where the port becomes unavailable between your check and the time you use it.  Depending on the context, checking that it is available is then useless or it can be better to take the ownership of the port at the time you want to check (and release if it is finally not used).

Comment: Is there a specific reason why not to use `bind()`?

Comment: @karastojko, basically I will be opening a Tcl Comm Server on that port by firing a Tcl command (using `Tcl_Eval`) after checking the port's availability. So, I don't want to bind the port, as I have to close immediately after binding.

Comment: @AProgrammer, that case has been welly handle. I have used some concepts of `critical section` and `mutex`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I was thinking of not firing another shell command. Anyways, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An even better idea is to make your code work completely without `netstat` altogether.

On Linux, all that `netstat` does (for your use case) is read the contents of `/proc/net/tcp`, which enumerates all ports in use.

All you have to do is open `/proc/net/tcp` yourself, and parse it. This becomes just an ordinary, boring, file parsing code. Can't get much more "crash-proof" than that.

You will find the documentation of the format of `/proc/net/tcp` in Linux manual pages.

In the unlikely event that you need to check `UDP` ports, this would be `/proc/net/udp`.

Of course, there is a race window between the time you check `/proc/net/tcp`, where someone can grab the port. But that's also true with `netstat` as well, and since that's going to be a much slower process, this will actually be an improvement, and reduce the race window significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for a way to check if `netstat` command is available, I won't try to suggest the other ways in C++. The shell way is checking return code of the following command:

```
command -v netstat
```

If `netstat` binary is available in `$PATH`, then the command returns `0`. In Bash it usually looks like this:

```sh
command -v netstat
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  netstat # ...
else
  echo >&2 "Error: netstat is not available"
fi
```

Or simply

```sh
command -v netstat >/dev/null && netstat # ...
```